# Wrong website metadata while redirecting a URL

Tags: javascript, php, url, http-redirect

I have built a URL shortener tool in PHP and jQuery, my goal is to show the destination URL's metadata on social media as twitter:name, twitter:image, etc.

Every time I post a generated link I get the metadata of the original website.

Example: let's pretend I've shortened `example.com/people.html` into `mytool.com/people`, if I use `mytool.com/people` on a browser, it redirects to the original URL, but if I post it on Twitter or Facebook, I get the `mytool.com`'s twitter:card metadata (name, description, image)

Here's the code I use to detect a short link in my index.php file and redirect it to the destination URL:

```
<?php 
    $shortEnd = $_GET['shortEnd'];
    if(isset($shortEnd)){
?>
        <script> 
            let destURL = // Here I get the destination URL with a query to my DB         
            
            // First quick redirect
            window.location.href = destURL; 
            
            // I recall another redirect 1 sec later as a try to get the destination URL metadata shown on social posts, but it doesn't work
            setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = destURL; }, 1000); 
        </script>
<?php 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: since `window.location.href = destURL` loads a new page, the timeout code will not be present to run

Comment: @DarkBee OP is wondering why `setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = destURL; }, 1000)` does nothing, not knowing that once a page is no longer inside a browser, its code naturally won't run

Comment: The Facebook scraper doesn't execute any client-side JS, the tools of other networks probably won't either. So the OG meta data is taken from your `mytool.com/people` URL here. And if you made it an HTTP redirect instead, Facebook would likely consider the other URL the canonical one - and then it might display that as the actual URL, instead of your shortener service one you wanted to share.

Comment: Why not `header("location:". $destURL);` ? Why the JS?

Comment: @mplungjan I'll try using PHP and see how it goes, thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @CBroe so you mean I should use PHP header("location") to the destination URL?

Comment: Then it should fetch the correct OG meta data, but it will also consider the target URL to be the canonical one for your shortener URL (_because_ it redirects) - which _could_ mean that your URL will be substituted for the target URL wherever Facebook might _display_ that URL in text form, and any likes/shares will be counted for the target URL only.

Comment: @mplungjan I'm getting CORS error :(

Comment: My suggestion does not use CORS. So you must have some other scripting too. If `mytool.com/people` leads to executing  `header("location: https://example.com/people.html");` where would the CORS come in?

Comment: @mplungjan Yes I have other PHP scripts, I use them to fetch data from JSON files and added the header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); on the top of my index.php file

Comment: From the information you have given so far, I cannot see the relevancy of the CORS on a "load a URL, get redirected to another" issue

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry, it's not easy to tell much by comments :( So, the problem is that I must run an ajax call in between my code in order to pass the JS variable of the destURL to a redirect.php file (that's because I fetch data from a JSON file). If I call the redirect.php file like example.com/reditect.php?destURL=https://example2.com, it works without CORS issues. Hope this helps

Comment: Then there are too many hops between your initial URL and the destination

Answer (score -3):

That's better if you use of header function like this :

`header('location: domain.com');`

esay and quick